# Does statically included jsp the name of the jsp that called it?

Tags: jsp

Following Google suggestions I want each page to list alternative language versions of the page

i.e for index.jsp

```
<head>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.widget.net/en/index.jsp" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.widget.net/es/index.jsp" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.widget.net/de/index.jsp" />
```

and for buy.jsp

```
<head>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.widget.net/en/buy.jsp" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.widget.net/es/buy.jsp" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.widget.net/de/buy.jsp" />
```

but the head file is the same file for all files because we do a static include in the calling jsp

i.e

```
<%@ include file="/layout/inc/head.jsp" %>
```

My question is, is there a way for head.jsp to determine the jsp that included it without it having to be passed the name as a paramter so I can parameterize head.jsp without having to modify all the files that call it.

**Solution**

A good point was made below, since I am caling it directly I have got it working as follows, I use scriptlets because more familar with Java code than jsp code.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="<%=request.getRequestURL().substring(0,request.getRequestURL().indexOf(language)) + "en" + request.getRequestURL().substring(request.getRequestURL().lastIndexOf("/"))%>"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="<%=request.getRequestURL().substring(0,request.getRequestURL().indexOf(language)) + "es" + request.getRequestURL().substring(request.getRequestURL().lastIndexOf("/"))%>"/>
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="<%=request.getRequestURL().substring(0,request.getRequestURL().indexOf(language)) + "de" + request.getRequestURL().substring(request.getRequestURL().lastIndexOf("/"))%>"/>
```

Comment: Answer depends on how those index/buy JSP files are usually requested. Given the alternate URLs, may I assume that they are requested just directly, without intervention of a front controller servlet? In other words, this expression  `${pageContext.request.requestURL}` already prints the full URL of the JSP file of interest?

Comment: It was just a question to exclude one and other so that the right answer can be prepared.

Comment: okay, if but out of interest if there was a front controller what approach would you take

Comment: The `getRequestURL()`, `getServletPath()` etc would point to JSP itself, not to the front controller. So in case of e.g. `getRequestURL()` you would need to grab the "browser address bar URL" as request attribute keyed with `RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that those JSP files are requested just directly, without intervention of a front controller servlet, you can use [`HttpServletRequest#getServletPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getServletPath()) for that. It returns the context-relative path to the JSP file, exactly the path which matched the container's `JspServlet`.

```
<c:set var="jsp" value="${pageContext.request.servletPath}" />
...
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.widget.net/en${jsp}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.widget.net/es${jsp}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.widget.net/de${jsp}" />
```

In case the current request URL already contains the language part, you can even use [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL()) to grab the full request URL and perform some string replacement on it.

```
<c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>
<c:set var="languagePath" value="/${language}" />
...
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="${fn:replace(url, languagePath, '/en')}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="${fn:replace(url, languagePath, '/es')}" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="${fn:replace(url, languagePath, '/de')}" />
```

As a suggestion, refactor the languages to a `List<String>` and loop over it using `<c:forEach>`.